# Placing an object from an array in a canvas

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, object, canvas

I'm making a game for school and wanted to place some trees in it. I thought it would be nice if i could make an array and place several trees from the array in the canvas. it seems that the array doesn't draw the trees on the canvas. I'm looking at it for hours and can't figure it out. Could somebody help me, please?

i've got two different .js documents. one is the general file and one for the trees.

First the general:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var horse = new Image();
horse.src = "ash.png"
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var xPos = 0;
var yPos = 0;
var animStep = 0;
var sx = 0;
var sy = 96;
var previousStep = Date.now();
var moveRight = false;
var moveLeft = false;
var moveUp = false;
var moveDown = false;
var achtergrond = 0;

//background 1
var grass = new Image();
grass.src = "grass.png";
var grassPattern;
grass.onload = function(){
        grassPattern = context.createPattern(grass,"repeat");
}

//background 2
var cave = new Image(); 
cave.src = "cave.png"; 
var cavePattern; 
    cave.onload = function(){ 
    cavePattern = context.createPattern(cave,"repeat"); 
    } 


//start drawfunction --------------------------------------------
function draw(){
//make an array:
var objects = [];
//make the chests:
objects.push( new Chest(100,200) );
objects.push( new Chest(200,200) );
objects.push( new Chest(200,100) );

for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    objects[i].draw();
}

update();
spritesheet();

    //spritesheet back in the canvas:
    if ( xPos > canvas.width ) {
            xPos = 0;
            achtergrond = 1;
    }
    if (xPos < -32){
        xPos = canvas.width;
        achtergrond = 0;
    }
    if ( yPos > canvas.height ) {
        // put the y to 0
        yPos = 0;
        achtergrond = 1;
    }
    if ( yPos < -32 ) {
        yPos = canvas.height;
        achtergrond = 0;
    }

    if (achtergrond == 0){
        context.fillStyle=grassPattern;
        context.fillRect (0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }
    else if (achtergrond == 1){
        context.fillStyle=cavePattern;
        context.fillRect (0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }


    context.drawImage(horse,animStep*32,sy,28,32,xPos,yPos,30,32);

    // call the function walk:
walk();

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();
//end draw function ----------------------------------------------------

$(document).keydown( function(evt) {
    if (evt.which == 39){ // if the right arrow key is pressed
        moveRight = true;
    }
    if (evt.which == 37){ // if the left arrow key is pressed
        moveLeft = true;
    }
    if (evt.which == 38){ // if the up arrow key is pressed
        moveUp = true;
    }
    if (evt.which == 40){ // if the down arrow key is pressed
        moveDown = true;
    }
});     
$(document).keyup( function(evt) {
    if (evt.which == 39){ // if the right arrow key is lifted
        moveRight = false;
    }
    if (evt.which == 37){ // if the left arrow key is lifted
        moveLeft = false;
    }
    if (evt.which == 38){ // if the up arrow key is lifted
        moveUp = false;
    }
    if (evt.which == 40){ // if the down arrow key is lifted
        moveDown = false;
    }
}); 

function update() {
    if (moveRight) {
        xPos += 4;
    } else if (moveLeft) {
        xPos -= 4;
    } else if (moveUp) {
        yPos -= 4;
    } else if (moveDown) {
        yPos += 4;
    }

}

function walk(){
if (Date.now() - previousStep > 1000/10) {
        animStep += 1;
            if (animStep == 5) {
                animStep = 0;
            }
        previousStep = Date.now();
    }

}

function spritesheet() {
        if (moveUp) { 
         sy = 65; 
        } else if (moveDown) { 
         sy = 0; 
        } else if (moveRight){ 
         sy = 96; 
        } else if (moveLeft) { 
         sy = 32; 
        }
    // als we in geen enkele richting lopen (! betekent niet) 
    if (!moveRight && !moveLeft && !moveUp && !moveDown) { 
    // staan we blijkbaar stil en gebruiken we de neutrale pose 
    sx = animStep = 0;
    } else { 
    // anders het huidige stapje maal de breedte van 1 stapje 
    sx = animStep * 32;
    } 
}

});
```

and the second .js file:

```
function Chest(x,y) {
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Chest Image object maken
var img = new Image();
img.src = "boom.png";

this.draw = function() {
context.drawImage(img,0,0,33,33,this.x,this.y,33,33);   
}

}
```

and ofcourse there is the canvas HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="rAF.js"></script>
 <script src="objects.js"></script>
 <script src="index.js"></script>
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 </head>

<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your Chest-function, declare the img.variable as local:

```
function Chest(x,y) {
//The function should be able to find these global variables without you delcaring them inside
//var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
//var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//declaring your x and y variables
this.x = x;
this.y = y;

// Chest Image object maken
this.img = new Image();
this.img.src = "boom.png";

this.draw = function() {
    context.drawImage(this.img,0,0,33,33,this.x,this.y,33,33);   
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But it still doesn't draw the trees in the canvas. the console gives no errors.. I got no clue about what can be wrong..

Comment: You're drawing the background-pattern after drawing the trees. The trees are probably hidden behind the grass. Move the for-loop for drawing the objects to the end of the draw()-function.